# JavaScript, getElementById(Array[Index]) not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome Extension in which I'm removing some Divs from a website that looks ugly. 
I'm trying to remove them in a loop, but it only seems to work when I'm doing it one line at a time.

What's wrong?

```
var node = document.getElementById("sharebuttons");
node.innerHTML ="";


var junkNodes=["monitoringnotice","mobilesitenote","adwrapper","fb-root","footer"];
for (var i = 0; i < junkNodes.length; i++) {
    node = document.getElementById(junkNodes[index]);
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

Thanks :)!

FIXED WORKING CODE:

```
var node = document.getElementById("sharebuttons");
node.innerHTML ="";


var junkNodes=["monitoringnotice","mobilesitenote","adwrapper","fb-root","footer"];
for (var i = 0; i < junkNodes.length; i++) {
    node = document.getElementById(junkNodes[i]);
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

Comment: So, you fixed the bug yourself? If so, please, either close the question or make the part with the correct code the an answer and accept it. Otherwise people will spend their time trying to figure out the problem just to find out that it's already been solved in the end. P.S. Welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have no `index` in the for loop, just `i`. I mean the iterating variable is `i` not `index`.

Try this:

```
node = document.getElementById(junkNodes[i]);
```

Comment: That's pretty embarrassing. :) Thanks!

Comment: @user3140655 np :) nice to have other eyes looking at the code sometimes... ◔ ⌣ ◔

Comment: @user3140655, if this was the solution of your problem you can also click to accept the answer. And btw, welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

`junkNodes[index]` should be `junkNodes[i]`. `index` is not defined...

Comment: Sergio beat me to it. :)